# How to save an entry from public to private database using CloudKit

Tags: swift, cloudkit

What is the most sensible way to save an entry from a public to private database using CloudKit

There is a similar question answered: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29455641/4445930), but I didn't quite understand the solution in those words. I don't necessarily need code answers (though always appreciated), but the linked question confused me here:

> That recordType would then have a field of type CKReference in which you save your user ID

Does it mean public entry has an array of references to all the users who saved it?

Currently I'm just creating a brand-new entry in the users private database based on the public one they chose to save. When I fetch public items I first query the saved items and cross reference so I can e.g. set the 'star' button to filled or unfilled. It feels very verbose and wrong, I would like to know how people manage this.

**Example:**

An app with two tabs/views - 'public' and 'private'. The public view is a list of strings (from the public database) and a star icon showing whether the user saved it or not, and the private view shows entries that are saved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's their solution. If you want to keep your own, just create a copy of the record in your private db. In my code I create models for each record type with;

```
let publicDB: CKDatabase
let privateDB: CKDatabase
var saveToDB : CKDatabase
```

then;

```
... other code retrieved record R from public DB
```

now;

```
saveToDB = privateDB

saveToDB.save(R, completionHandler:
{ 
    (record, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil)
    {
                       // ... error handling...
                       completion(error)
   }
   else
   {
       completion(nil)
                   
                       
    }
})
```